# Boss accuses me of not doing my job, calls my parents into a meeting

Tags: bullying, discipline

I work at the same company as my parents. My boss asked the director to call my parents into a meeting with me to discuss problems he has had with me for the last 2 years. My boss never documented anything until a few day's before the meeting. He mentioned a few things off and on but never made a big deal out of any of it. I have never been given a verbal or written reprimand.

I was accused of not doing my job in an area where I was not assigned to work, in other words I wasn't there. A coworker that bullied me for months accused me of sleeping on the job, I did not. I asked for a copy of the documentation and was told yes but have not recieved it. I was also accused of hiding in a room but I am diagnosed with depression/severe anxiety disorder.

Is any of this ok?

Comment: What happens if you just let it go? Are they planning to fire you? Have they told you so?

Comment: I was told that I could not make 1 mistake. If I do than I will be terminated.

Comment: I am trying and failing to understand why your parents would be involved in such a meeting. That is a severe breech of confidentiality. They have no business in a meeting lile that even if they work in the same place unless they are your immediate bosses.

Comment: Which country is that in? I'd consider pulling the parents into such a matter unacceptable in the US or EU, but there might be other countries this would be considered acceptable.

Comment: @JimG, I don't see the value of creating a "parents" tag on The Workplace.  If you do, please bring it up on meta, identifying questions or types of question other than this one, *that would be on-topic*, where such a tag would fit.  Thank you.

Comment: Obviously someone is attacking one or both of your parents. You are just suffering collateral damage.

Answer (score 13):

Whether it is OK is not the question. Life isn't fair and what has happened can't be made to unhappen.  What to do from here is the question.

First since they didn't appear to give you any specific plan for how to improve, you need to develop one. It doesn't matter if you agree with the assertions or not, you have to show the attitude that you are are fixing the problem. Write out each point where they felt your performance was lacking and then write what you can do about it.

Concerning not doing a job you had never been assigned to do, I'd suggest you talk to you boss about how he wants you to confirm what you are wokring on and what things you think you have been assigned to so that nothing slips through the cracks again. You want to go over priorities with him daily if possible but weekly at a minumum.  Ask for a written response from him  confirming your priorities so there is no question what you have been assigned to do that day.

Perhaps it was his fault he didn't tell you to work in that area or perhpas he did tell you and you forgot or perhaps he sent an email that you missed reading. It doesn't really matter what happened as he thinks you should have done the work. What matters is taking steps to ensure that you are doing what he thinks you are supposed to be doing.

Once you have a plan in place for what specific steps you can take to improve your performance, then do them. Make sure to check in with your boss frequently about whether he has seen imporvement and what else you could do. You need to learn to communicate with your boss better, it should not have been a surprise that he was unhappy with your performance.

I am a senior person and I still confer with my boss several times a week about priorities becasue I need to know that what he thinks is most important is what I think is most important. I know him and the company pretty well, so 95% or more of the time I have the correct priorities but it is those ones you missed that come back to bite you.

The other thing I do is make sure my boss knows immediately when there is a problem I will not be able resolve quickly that will affect clients or other employees. I tell him what I am doing to fix the problem, but the one thing you never want is for your boss to hear about a problem in your area from someone else especially someone he reports to.

You need to start managing your boss's expectations. Because he is unhappy with your performance, right now you need to overcommunicate.  Most likely what you consider overcommunicating is still undercommunicating in his eyes, so ask him exactly what he expects from you in terms of information on what you are doing and them give him more than what he asked for.

Once you have regained your boss's trust, you need to discuss having your parents in the meeting with you. This was 100% inappropriate on his part. It was not their business, they did not belong there. There is no point bringing it up right now, but later on you need to make sure he understands that you are an adult and would appreciate being treated as one from then on.

Immediately, I would talk to my parents and ask them to excuse themselves from any further meetings if they are invited. Your performance is none of their business. You are an adult, they do not have supervision over your actions as an adult even if you live at home. What you do at work is none of their business unless you directly report to them. It is appalling to me that they did not immediately leave the meeting when it became clear what it was about. This was highly unprofessional on their part and on your bosses part. Make sure your parents don't overstep their bounds in the future and that they know this is your problem to handle not theirs.